# Every point of an interval $[0;1]$ lies in $k$ subintervals $A_i$. Show that $k \le \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that every point of an interval $X=[0, 1]$ lies in at least $k$ subintervals $A_i \subset X$, $i=1, ..., n$. Show that $$k \le \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|$$
where $|A_i|$ denotes the length of $A_i$.

**My thoughts:**

Let's consider $k$ copies of $X$. We will denote j-th copy as $X^j$.

If we would be able to cover them with $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ then we're done.

(it is also enough to left uncovered the set of measure zero in every copy).

Let's fix an arbitrary point $x \in X^1$. There exists $1 \le i_1 \lt ... <i_k \le n$ such that $x \in A_{i_j}, j=1,...,k$. Then we will use $A_{i_j}$ to cover everything it can on the copy $X^j$. Now, let's choose another point $x \in X^1$ and repeat the process.

There is a hard part in this proof. I can't understand why it can not be the case when we used all our $A_i$ but didn't fully cover every copy $X^j$(or didn't left uncovered the set of measure zero in every copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy: $\sum_i \chi_{A_i}  (x) \geq k$ for each $x \in X$. [Each term is $0$ or $1$ and at least $k$ terms are equal to $1$].  Integrating we get $k \leq \sum|A_i|$,

Comment: Nice job:) thank you very much

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your solution can be easily extended to an abstract measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$